# Spring boot rest requestbody and @valid not working when object is null/empty

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest, spring-validation

I am trying to apply not null validation on an attribute of my request which is instructedAmount but it is not working. I have a Spring Boot (V2.3.0.RELEASE) application with the following endpoints:

```
@Validated
public class TestController {
@PostMapping(value = "/test/pay")
    public ResponseEntity<IPSPaymentResponse> validatePayt(@Valid @RequestBody InstantPaymentRequest instantPaymentRequest) {
        log.debug("start validatePayment method {}", instantPaymentRequest);
....
```

The InstantPaymentRequest is as follows:

```
@Data
@Validated
public class InstantPaymentRequest {
    @Valid
    private PaymentIdentificationRequest paymentIdentification;
    @NotBlank(message = "transactionTypeCode.required")
    private String transactionTypeCode;
    @Valid
    private InstructedAmount instructedAmount;
    @Valid
    private CustomerRequest debtor;
```

The instructed amount is as follows:

```
    @Data
public class InstructedAmount {

    @NotBlank(message = "currency.required")
    private String currency;
    @NotBlank(message = "value.required")
    private String value;
}
```

Basically when the instructedAmount  is provided in the payload but for example I miss currency attribute in payload, the validation is working fine, the non null error message is displayed correctly and my rest controller endpoint is not called.

However when **instructedAmount**  is not provided in the payload, no mandatory error message is displayed and my rest endpoint is called, it this the correct way or I am missing something?

I thought since attribute of InstructedAmount cannot be null then  InstructedAmount  also cannot be null/empty.

How to add InstructedAmount not null validation in the above scenario with annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@NotNull` together with `@Valid`:

```
@NotNull
@Valid
private InstructedAmount instructedAmount;
```

From https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-object-graph-validation:

> Note that null values are getting ignored during cascaded validation.